# How to export environment variables with spaces?

Tags: environment-variables

I want to set an environment variable that has space in it.

It is a path to a folder and the folder name is:

```
/home/mehrabib/my video
```

I edit .bashrc and add the following line to it:

```
export $VIDEO=/home/mehrabib/my\ video
```

and run these commands:

```
echo $VIDEO
cd $VIDEO
```

The result is:

```
/home/mehrabib/my video
/home/mehrabib/my :no such file or directory
```

I change it to

```
export $VIDEO=/home/mehrabib/my\\\ video
```

and run these commands:

```
echo $VIDEO
cd $VIDEO
```

The result is:

```
/home/mehrabib/my\ video
/home/mehrabib/my\ :no such file or directory
```

What should I do?

Comment: Wrap it in quotes, like `VAR="/home/mehrabib/my video"`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You should do

```
export VIDEO="/home/mehrabib/my video"
```

and to sum Dan's comments up also do

```
cd "$VIDEO"
```

which will expand to

```
cd "/home/mehrabib/my video"
```

again.

Personally, I've come to prefer the `${VIDEO}` syntax.

Comment: The `$` is needed when `cd`ing into the directory. `cd "VIDEO"` will not work.

Answer (score 14):

You can also substitute special characters - use * as a wildcard to substitute for the space.

VIDEO="/home/mehrabib/m*o"

Comment: ...unless you have another directory there which starts with 'm' and ends in 'o'; like "mono" :)

Comment: I'm was facing this on mac OSX, for me the quotes didn't work, instead the * symbol worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try to quote `VIDEO`: `cd "$VIDEO"`.

Comment: And do the same to `export VIDEO="/home/mehrabib/my video"`