# Defining a shortcut to open Chrome from the command line on MacOS

Tags: bash, macos, google-chrome, command-line

I'd like to open `.html` and `.xml` files from the command line using Google Chrome on a Mac. Usually I just used the `open` command, but for `.xml` files I've noticed that the default application is XCode, so I'd like to specify the application with the `-a` argument.

The following command works:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:MacOS kurtpeek$ open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" ~/Documents/Seattle/comparables.xml
```

Here I've enclosed the path to `Google Chrome` - which has spaces in it - in quotes. In order to make this easier to type in the future, I'd like to define an environment variable `$chrome` in by `.bash_profile` containing this path, which I did as follows:

```
export chrome="/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
```

The `echo` command does print this out:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:~ kurtpeek$ echo $chrome
/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
```

However, if I try to rerun the `open -a` with this environment variable to specify the application, I get the following error:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:~ kurtpeek$ open -a $chrome Documents/Seattle/comparables.xml
The files /Users/kurtpeek/Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google and /Users/kurtpeek/Chrome do not exist.
```

Apparently, in this case, the Bash shell does not 'recognize' the quotation marks I put in the definition of `chrome`. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [Set environment variable with having space linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740683/set-environment-variable-with-having-space-linux), this can be done by enclosing `$chrome` in quotes:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:~ kurtpeek$ open -a "$chrome" Documents/Seattle/comparables.xml
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:~ kurtpeek$
```

and the XML document gets opened in Chrome:

[image]

**Update**

It would appear (from https://superuser.com/questions/157484/start-google-chrome-on-mac-with-command-line-switches/157486#157486) that the `open` command looks in the `Applications` directory by default. So it suffices to just pass `"Google Chrome"` as an `-a` argument:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:~ kurtpeek$ open -a "Google Chrome" Documents/Seattle/comparables.xml
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:~ kurtpeek$
```