# How to add - to environment variables in git bash

Tags: docker, git-bash

I tried to set the following environment variables so that I could quickly start the docker container

```
 export doup=docker-compose up -d
```

However, the following error occurred and it could not be set up.

```
bash: export: `-d': not a valid identifier
```

Is there a way to set - to an environment variable?

Comment: don't you want to define a function or an alias instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to export environment variables with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740683/how-to-export-environment-variables-with-spaces)

Comment: It's now about the `-`, but about the spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to quote it:

```
export doup='docker-compose up -d'
```

but what you probably actually want is an alias:

```
alias doup='docker-compose up -d'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Resolved without incident.

By the way, regarding the use of alias and export, am I correct in my understanding as follows?

In alias,If you want to easily execute a command that you will use many times e.g. If you want to simplify docker container launching, as in this case

In export,When you want to execute a file in a registered directory only by its filename, not by its full path. e.g. To avoid executing linux commands with full paths, set the following in export.

/usr/bin/

Comment: Your understanding of aliases is correct. But an environment variable is just a global variable. If you want to make your shell find certain binaries, you append the full path to that binary into the special `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thank you. I understood very well. You are wonderful.